# Azure OAuth 2.0 devicecode added to browser at launch time

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0

I have a devicecode authentication flow in PowerShell that requires the user to login with first the device code and then with the correct credentials.

The same routine was used in Connect-AzAccount in version 1.9.5 of Az.Account, but in the current version of that module, the code seems to be added to the browser at launch time and the end user only has to type in the correct credentials.

I have both the devicecode and the url in my code, but how do I get the code appended to the url or browser process, when launching the browser for authentication?

I have this code:

```
$code #contains the code the user should paste
$url #contains the device authentication url
Write-Host $code
Start-Process $url
```

Comment: Construct the URL with all it needs and pass that on a variable you pass elsewhere. Similar to what you'd do to build a custom file name from various string resources.

Comment: Yes, but what are the needs for this very specific url?